# Emails not being searched properly in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed a few documents in elasticsearch which have email ids as a field. But when I query for a specific email id, the search results are showing all the documents without filtering.

This is the query I have used

```
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
     "mail-id": "abc@gmail.com"
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, your `mail-id` field is analyzed by the standard analyzer which will tokenize the email `abc@gmail.com` into the following two tokens:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "abc",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "gmail.com",
    "start_offset" : 4,
    "end_offset" : 13,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  } ]
}
```

What you need instead is to create a custom analyzer using the [UAX email URL tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html), which will tokenize email addresses as a one token.

So you need to define your index as follows:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/people -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "person": {
      "properties": {
        "mail-id": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

After creating that index, you can see that the email `abc@gmail.com` will be tokenized as a single token and your search will work as expected.

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/people/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty' -d 'abc@gmail.com'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 13,
    "type" : "<EMAIL>",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use the default mappings. Elasticsearch has uax_url_email tokenizers which would identify the urls and emails as a single entity/token.
You can read more about this [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html) and [here](https://qbox.io/blog/applying-elasticsearch-analyzers)

Comment: Hi Vineet.. can you please have a look at this
[Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408074/search-for-phrases-with-special-characters-attachment-contentelastic-search?noredirect=1#comment62323248_37408074)