# Search for phrases with special characters - Attachment Content(Elastic Search)

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

Is there any way in which I can search for phrases with special characters in the content of the attached file? for eg: I want to search for `asn@xyz.com` in the contents of all the indexed files.

I actually tried it on my code and it seems to be like '@' is not considered and instead it is searching for asn, xyz and com separately and generating results. How can I solve this?

TIA

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124725/emails-not-being-searched-properly-in-elasticsearch/35124883#35124883

Comment: @Val Thanks for the link Val. But it takes care of only emails. But what about other special characters ? And moreover Is it possible to add multiple analyzers on the same field name? Because as I'm working on attachments and for better search performance i added "English" analyzer already on the Attachment.content field. So is it possible to add another analyzer?

Comment: I suggest reading [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html). This is a broader subject than it may seem. After you start playing with queries and having issues, post a more specific and detailed question.