# Query email column in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to query a column in elastic search that contains email addresses with the following filter.

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [

    {
      "term": {
        "from":"andrei@hotmail.com123"

      }
    }
  ]
}
},
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
   "aggs": {}
}
```

if I try andrei it works fine. Also if I try hotmail.com123. However if I try to search for andrei@hotmail.com123 nothing is returned. Any clues why?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124725/emails-not-being-searched-properly-in-elasticsearch/35124883#35124883

Answer (score 0):

We found this answer and it seems to work, considering that we replace in code the @ with an empty string

```
{
"query": {

        {
    "match" : {
        "from" : {
            "query" : "andrei hotmail.com123",
            "operator" : "and"
        }
    }
        }
]}}
}
```